# How to perform arithmetic operations on the output of a shell command

Tags: tcsh

I'm trying to count the number of entries in a set of log files. Some of these logs have lines that should not be counted (the number of these remains constant). The way I'd like to go about this is a Perl script that iterates over a hash, which maps log names to a one-liner that gets the number of entries for that particular log (I figured this would be easier to maintain than dozens of if-else statements)

Getting the number of lines is simple:

`wc -l [logfile] | cut -f1 -d " "`

The issue is when I need to subtract, say, 1 or 2 from this value. I tried the following:

`expr( wc -l [logfile] | cut -f1 -d " " ) - 1`

But this results in an error:

`Badly placed ()'s.`

`: Command not found.`

How do I perform arithmetic operations on the output of a shell command? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your tags are excessively inclusive: which shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit clunky to shell out to `wc` and `cut` just to count the number of lines in a file.

Your requirement isn't very clear, but this Perl code creates a hash that relates every log file in the current directory to the number of lines it contains. It works by reading each file into an array of lines, and then evaluating that array in scalar context to give the line count. I hope it's obvious how to subtract a constant delta from each line count.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %lines;

for my $logfile ( glob '*.log' ) {

    my $num_lines = do {
        open my $fh, '<', $logfile or die qq{Unable to open "$logfile" for input: $!};
        my @lines = <$fh>;
    };

    $lines{$logfile} = $num_lines;
}
```

---

**Update**

After a comment from `w.k`, I think this version may be rather nicer

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %lines;

for my $logfile ( glob '*.log' ) {
    open my $fh, '<', $logfile or die qq{Unable to open "$logfile" for input: $!};
    1 while <$fh>;
    $lines{$logfile} = $.;
}
```

Comment: I think, it should be `$lines{$logfile} = @lines`, but isn't it too memory consuming? I'd go for something like this: 
`while ( <$fh> )  {
  $lines{$logfile} = $. if eof();
}`

Comment: @w.k.: No, not `@lines` but there was a mistake. Thanks. And my version will read the whole file into memory (and then immediately discard it) but there's no reason why that should be a problem unless the log files are enormous. It's important to put clarity of the code first, and optimise later if necessary.

Comment: @w.k: Your alternative is probably better as `1 while <$fh>; $lines{$logfile} = $.;`

Comment: So `$.` has last line number after while loop is ended?

Comment: And why not `$lines{$logfile} = @lines`? Here `@lines` is evaluated in scalar context and should give number of lines.

Comment: @w.k: Yes, `$.` isn't scoped. And that is just a style choice, but the rest of the code would have to be changed as `@lines` has been deleted after the `do` block.

Answer (score 1):

To display one less than the number of lines with `bash` or any bourne-like shell:

```
echo $(( $(wc -l <file) - 1 ))
```

#### Discussion

To get the number of lines, you used:

```
wc -l logfile | cut -f1 -d " "
```

`cut` is required here because `wc` copies the file name to its output.  To avoid that, and thus avoid the need for `cut`, supply the input to `wc` via stdin:

```
wc -l <logfile
```

In modern (POSIX) shells, arithmetic is done with `$((...))`.  Thus, we can substract one from the number of lines via:

```
$(( $(wc -l <file) - 1 ))
```

Comment: I think the OP is using `tcsh`, since the error is the same as what I get in `tcsh` ... (question was tagged as `bash` and `tcsh`, though :-/)

Comment: I ended up going with Borodin's solution, but this was helpful. I forgot about the double parenthesis construct. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers went in the direction of solving your issue in `perl`, which you mentioned but your own experiments were in shell syntax.

You indicated `tcsh` but `expr` is Posix shell syntax.

Here is an example of a `csh` script that counts the number of lines in a file whose name it is passed and then does arithmetic on the number of lines.

```
set lines=`wc -l < $1`
@ oneless = ($lines - 1)
echo "There are $lines in $1 and minus one makes $oneless"
```

**Test:**

```
csh count.csh count.csh
There are 3 lines in count.csh and minus one makes 2
```